# Dual WAN with 4G load balancing

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, gsm

My specific issue is that some times during the day my internet gets exceedingly slow, however often it does not actually drops completely, so I've been looking into using a dual WAN router, and use a SIM card as a backup connection.

Since the issue is the network getting too slow, setting my 4G connection to fail-over won't work, since it will likely not switch when I would like it to.

So it comes to load balancing. What I would like to do is to configure a router so that when my connection gets slow, it switches some of the traffic to the 4G connection.

The issue I've been encountering is that the options I find are usually like setting fixed weights to the connections, which is not desirable (if my regular ISP is working fine, I don't any connection using 4G at all), or to make the 4G connection to kick in when the traffic is *above* a certain threshold, which again is not what I want.

Now that I think about this, I started to wonder if this is even feasible, since I don't think that it would be easy for the router to detect that my ISP is being slow, rather than the website I am visiting.

I would like help to understand if what I want is feasible, and if yes, I would be more than happy if you could recommend me some router models which do have this feature that I want.

Ideally I would like to have a single router doing the load balancing, but if the only option is to have a separate load balancer device, then I might have to go with this option.